# PDFsharp - Trying to make a table of contents for all the files I just merged with links to pages

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am trying to create a Table of Contents (with page links) for files that are being concatenated together using PDFsharp.

I've gotten to the point where I am trying to add a link to text I just wrote. Can someone please provide some direction?

```
    public static void combinePDFs(List<string> filenames)
    {
        List<PdfDocument> pdfs = new List<PdfDocument>();

        foreach (string f in filenames)
        pdfs.Add(PdfReader.Open(f, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import));

        List<int> pagesInDoc = new List<int>();

        using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
        {
            PdfDocument doc = TOC();
            //CopyPages(TOC(), outPdf);
            foreach (var p in pdfs)
                pagesInDoc.Add(CopyPages(p, doc));



            doc.Save(@"...\file1and2.pdf");
        }

        PdfDocument TOC()
        {
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            XFont font = new XFont("Calibri", 14, XFontStyle.Bold);
            gfx.DrawString("Table of Contents", font, XBrushes.DarkBlue,
                new XRect(0,0,page.Width,page.Height)
                ,XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            var xrect = new XRect(10, 20, 300, 20);

            //I am trying to hard code my first link here
            gfx.DrawString("CRA", font, XBrushes.DarkBlue
                , xrect, XStringFormats.CenterLeft);
            page.AddDocumentLink(new PdfRectangle(xrect), 2);

            return doc;
        }

        int CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
            {
                to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
            }
            return from.PageCount;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it let's you do this, you still need to add a transform:

```
page.AddDocumentLink(new PdfRectangle(xrect), 2);

to

page.AddDocumentLink(new PdfRectangle(gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(xrect)), 2);
```